# Adding a Widget : what to put in plugin URL

Tags: widgets

I am signing up to add a widget to wordpress.org here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add/

What do I put for the field "Plugin URL"?

Would that URL be the svn repository I am currently hosting my widget (a personal svn repo)  or would that be a URL of a website where the widget is being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding a plugin to WordPress.org plugin repository you need to host the plugin somewhere (anywhere) and that is the "Plugin URL" so the good guys at WordPress could download it, test it and approve it to be listed.
so just upload it to your host and enter the url to the zip file.
Once it gets approved you will get access to http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/your_plugin_name/ using your WordPress.org user name and password.

> Here's some handy links to help you
>   get started.
>
> Using Subversion with the WordPress
>   Plugins Directory
>   http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/svn/
>
> FAQ about the WordPress Plugins
>   Directory
>   http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/faq/
>
> WordPress Plugins Directory readme.txt
>   standard
>   http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/readme.txt
>
> readme.txt validator:
>   http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/validator/

this is what you get in the "WordPress.org Plugins Request Approved" email notification.

Hope This helps.

Answer (score -1):

*Plugin URL* points to a resource where you describe your plugin. It could be a blog post, a GitHub repository or a dedicated website. You may even leave it out.

The value is **not** used by the WP people to approve your plugin; so it should not link to a zip archive.